# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I don't really know how to program... I was working on this for a Computer Science Class

> Instruction: Use nested loops to print out the square word pattern show below.
>   I'm guessing the error is in the toString method, but I can't spot where.

the desired output is: (when input is SQUARE)

```
SQUARE
Q    R
U    A
A    U
R    Q
ERAUQS
```

The code:
    import static java.lang.System.*;

```
class BoxWord
{
   private String word;

 public BoxWord()
 {
  word="";
 }

 public BoxWord(String s)
 {
   setWord(s);
 }

 public void setWord(String w)
 {
   word=w;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  String output=word +"\n";
  for(int i =0;i<word.length(); i++){
    output += word.charAt(i);
    for(int j = 2; j<word.length();j++)
      output += " ";
    output+= word.charAt(word.length()-(i-1))+ "\n";
  }

  for(int k=0; k<word.length(); k++)
   output+= word.charAt(k);


  return output+"\n";
 }
}
```

main:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab11f
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
     BoxWord test = new BoxWord("square");
     out.println(test);   

 }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add stack tracke

Comment: If the input is `square`, what is the output supposed to be?

Comment: Use an IDE and debug the program. It is not that hard.

Comment: Look what happens when i = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I will explain the modifications in comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String word = "square";
    String output = word + "\n"; // Initialize with the word
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++) { // From '1' to 'length - 1' because we don't want to iterate over the first and last characters
        output += word.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length() - 2; j++) // To add spaces
            output += " ";
        output += word.charAt(word.length() - (i + 1)) + "\n";
    }
    for (int k = word.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--) // Add word in reverse
        output += word.charAt(k);

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

**Output:**

```
square
q    r
u    a
a    u
r    q
erauqs
```

Comment: I made the int i = 1 instead so later i did word.length() -1-i

Answer (score 0):

On the first two iterations of this loop you are going to have an error:

```
for(int i =0;i<word.length(); i++){
    output += word.charAt(i);
    for(int j = 2; j<word.length();j++)
      output += " ";
    output+= word.charAt(word.length()-(i-1))+ "\n";
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
```

This is equivalent to `word.length() - i + 1` which is going to be an error when `i` is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString()
 {
  String output=word +"\n";
  for(int i =0;i<word.length(); i++){
    output += word.charAt(i);
    for(int j = 2; j<word.length();j++)
      output += " ";
    output+= word.charAt(word.length()-(i-1))+ "\n";
  }
```

**output+= word.charAt(word.length()-(i-1))+ "\n";** this line is making string index out of bound exception